# Good CMake Style: Inherit Properties

Tags: cmake, build-system

Daniel Pfeifer, in his presentation "Effective CMake",
makes a point, that it is advisable to avoid variable 
definitions as much as possible.

Now, how does one get properties into a variety of build 
targets. That is, for example

```
   target_include_directories(base_IncludeFlags
                              INTERFACE 
                              first/dir
                              second/dir
                              ...)
```

defines a set of include directories. Instead of defining 
the exact same include directories for `target_a`, `target_b`, 
and `target_c`, I would like to let those targets *inherit* 
the include directories from 'base_target', with something like

```
target_link_libraries(target_a PUBLIC base_IncludeFlags) 
target_link_libraries(target_b PUBLIC base_IncludeFlags)
target_link_libraries(target_c PUBLIC base_IncludeFlags)
```

where `base_IncludeFlags` is shall not be a real physical target,
rather something like an **abstract base class** or **interface**.

On the other hand, I do not want to use `include_directories` 
since this affects all targets. Is it better to use `foreach`?
What is the most elegant way to do this? Shall I make `base_target`
a library and add dependencies?

Comment: "Shall I make base_target a library and add dependencies?" - Yes you may create INTERFACE library, add common include directories to it, and link with a library whenever you need these common include directories.

Comment: If you adorn your response with some sample code, I guess this would be the solution.

Comment: Hm, actually my previose comment was the first thought about the question text. But I don't quite understand a problem you want to resolve. According to your code, you **already have** target `base_target`, which could only be a library or an executable (otherwise you cannot call `target_inclide_directories` for it). If it is a library, you may just use `target_link_libraries` for it. If it is an executable, why do you want to inherit its properties? Please, elaborate this. Patterns, provided by CMake, are not only for code, but for *design* too. Using good code for bad design isn't so good.

Comment: What I want is a target that is not actually physically produced, but which propagates some common properties.

Comment: "What I want is a target that is not actually physically produced, but which propagates some common properties." - Yes, this explains a lot. Could you add that (or similar) wording into your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want is a target that is not actually physically produced, but which propagates some common properties.

Exactly for that purpose CMake has [INTERFACE library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_library.html#id6) - container for different properties, which are propagated when this library is linked into another target.

Example:

```
# Create "container" target
add_library(base_target INTERFACE)

# Add some INTERFACE properties for that target
target_include_directories(base_target INTERFACE 
                          first/dir
                          second/dir)

# Some 'other_target' (library or executable) may easily consume all common properties:
target_link_libraries(other_target PUBLIC base_target)
# Now 'other_target' has aforementioned include directories too.
# Instead of PUBLIC other linking types (PRIVATE, INTERFACE) may be used.
```

Comment: this only works for whitelisted properties. Custom properties cannot be propagated using INTERFACE library.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most elegant way to do this?

Consider that CMake files are often read and edited by people who aren't experts in CMake. Rather than going for elegance, you may consider going for simplicity: keep it simple, stupid.

If you introduce abstractions, hidden implicit behavior of any kind, it will be harder for everybody to maintain the CMake file.

For me, simple in this case would mean copying (duplicating) the entries, if there are just 2-3. If there's more libraries, I'd put the headers in a variable. The "Effective CMake" presentation makes a point to avoid *unnecessary*, single-use variable definitions. I'd argue that this header list would be a helpful variable, and worth creating.

Comment: For the 2-3 application, I guess the 'foreach' approach is in your sense. As for the inheritance approach a 'virtual library' identified by its naming such as 'XXX_include_flags_notalib' would be equally transparent.